# How to I find the person who has taught the most classes

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, sql-order-by, inner-join

I want to try and find the employee who has taught the most classes as the position `Teacher`. So in this I want to print out `Nick`, as he has taught the most classes as a `Teacher`.

However, I am getting the error:

> ERROR: column "e.name" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function Position: 24

```
CREATE TABLE employees (
  id integer primary key,
  name text
);

CREATE TABLE positions (
  id integer primary key,
  name text
);

CREATE TABLE teaches (
  id integer primary key,
  class text,
  employee integer,
  position integer,
  foreign key (employee) references employees(id),
  foreign key (position) references positions(id)
);

INSERT INTO employees (id, name) VALUES
(1, 'Clive'), (2, 'Johnny'), (3, 'Sam'), (4, 'Nick');

INSERT INTO positions (id, name) VALUES
(1, 'Assistant'), (2, 'Teacher'), (3, 'CEO'), (4, 'Manager');

INSERT INTO teaches (id, class, employee, position) VALUES
(1, 'Dancing', 1, 1), (2, 'Gardening', 1, 2),
(3, 'Dancing', 1, 2), (4, 'Baking', 4, 2),
(5, 'Gardening', 4, 2), (6, 'Gardening', 4, 2),
(7, 'Baseball', 4, 1), (8, 'Baseball', 2, 1),
(9, 'Baseball', 4, 2);
```

The SQL statement I am trying to use:

```
SELECT count(t.class), e.name
FROM positions p
JOIN teaches t
ON p.id = t.position
JOIN employees e
ON e.id = t.employee
WHERE p.name = 'Teacher'
GROUP BY t.employee;
```

I've been working on this on a sql fiddle:
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/a8e19c/3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query looks pretty good. You just need to fix the `GROUP BY` clause, so it is consistent with the columns in the `SELECT` clause. Then `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT count(*) cnt_classes, e.name
FROM positions p 
INNER JOIN teaches   t ON p.id = t.position
INNER JOIN employees e ON e.id = t.employee
WHERE p.name = 'Teacher' 
GROUP BY e.id              --> primary key of "employees"
ORDER BY cnt_classes DESC  --> order by descending count of classes
LIMIT 1                    --> keep the first row only
```

Comment: I think you mean GROUP BY e.name

Comment: @mister_smythers: I do mean `e.id`. That’s the PK of the employee table, `name` is fonctionnaly dependent on `id`.

Comment: You are correct.  I'm not sure why I'm not able to do that in my DB with teachers.id as the primary column.  Seems to be the same query.
`select count(*) sec_count, teachers.teacher_number from teachers
inner join sections on teachers.id = sections.teacher
inner join schools on teachers.school = schools.id
group by teachers.id
order by sec_count desc`
Does this code only work if `teachers.teacher_number` is unique in my DB?  And then it would only work if `e.name` is unique in the response you posted?

Answer (score 0):

In your select you are using aggregate `COUNT` that counts all lines  in each group (`GROUP BY t.employee`) but you don't aggregate `e.name`.

So for Nick you basically select 4 rows each for one class  that have two columns - class name and teacher name. Then you ask server to count class names in Nicks group (by his employee id), that aggregates 4 rows into one with value 4 but you don't do anything about teacher name so you are left with invalid structure where you have 1 row for classes count column and 4 rows for teacher name. Same for other teachers. And that's what server is complaining about. Easiest way to fix that is to add e.name to `GROUP BY`, that will squeeze those 4 rows of same value into one.

To get teacher that teaches most classes you then only need to sort results by class count descending order and limit result count to 1. That will give you result row with highest class count.

Updated fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/a8e19c/7

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the error because you need to need to have every column you're selecting (e.name in this example in the GROUP BY clause, otherwise SQL doesn't know how to group and return a count for that column. You'll also want to use TOP(1) and order by if you want to return the person with the most.

```
SELECT TOP(1) count(*), e.name
FROM teaches t 
INNER JOIN positions p ON t.position = p.id
INNER JOIN employees e ON e.id = t.employee
WHERE p.name = 'Teacher'
GROUP BY e.name
ORDER BY count(*) DESC;
```